# Scan beacons and find closest one in swift

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I want to develop a swift project that detect beacons around the iPhone and decide which one is the closest one. I make a lot of searchings but i didn't get something useful for me(i am new at swift developing so i can't figure this out) can anybody help me about this so i can getting started.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
    let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
}
```

}

From my testing, the beacons arrive in the beacons array already sorted from closest to farthest, with unknowns coming in first, before the closest known beacon. That said, I can't find anywhere in the documentation mentions this, so I can't recommend relying on this to always happen in a production application. For the sake of simplicity here, we're going to just grab the first element in the beacons array as the closest beacon. And we filter the array to remove beacon with unknow range

Comment: thanks for your comment i will use this but firstly i must find devices then decide which is closest. I am using this but not get anything. I think i have a problem with uuid. Which uuid should i use

Comment: Default UUID of iBeacon is B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D.

Comment: You can check this [page](https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868188-How-to-modify-UUID-Major-and-Minor-values-) if u want to change it. plz do not forget to mark my answer as resolved if it has helped you :) thx !

Answer (score 0):

Finding the closest beacon can be surprisingly complex.  Sometimes beacons have an accuracy value of -1 if no RSSI (signal strength), sometimes beacons drop out of the scanned list if they aren't detected in the last second.   Here's some Swift code I use to the basics:

```
let expirationTimeSecs = 5.0
public var closestBeacon: CLBeacon? = nil
var trackedBeacons: Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>
var trackedBeaconTimes: Dictionary<String, NSDate>

override init() {
  trackedBeacons = Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>()
  trackedBeaconTimes = Dictionary<String, NSDate>()
}

public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  let now = NSDate()
  for beacon in beacons {
    let key = keyForBeacon(beacon)
    if beacon.accuracy < 0 {
      NSLog("Ignoring beacon with negative distance")
    }
    else {
      trackedBeacons[key] = beacon
      if (trackedBeaconTimes[key] != nil) {
        trackedBeaconTimes[key] = now
      }
      else {
        trackedBeaconTimes[key] = now
      }
    }
  }
  purgeExpiredBeacons()
  calculateClosestBeacon()
}

func calculateClosestBeacon() {
  var changed = false
    // Initialize cloestBeaconCandidate to the latest tracked instance of current closest beacon
    var closestBeaconCandidate: CLBeacon?
    if closestBeacon != nil {
      let closestBeaconKey = keyForBeacon(closestBeacon!)
      for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
        if key == closestBeaconKey {
          closestBeaconCandidate = trackedBeacons[key]
        }
      }
    }

    for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
      var closer = false
      let beacon = trackedBeacons[key]
      if (beacon != closestBeaconCandidate) {
        if beacon!.accuracy > 0 {
          if closestBeaconCandidate == nil {
            closer = true
          }
          else if beacon!.accuracy < closestBeaconCandidate!.accuracy {
            closer = true
          }
        }
        if closer {
          closestBeaconCandidate = beacon
          changed = true
        }
      }
    }
    if (changed) {
      closestBeacon = closestBeaconCandidate
    }
}

func keyForBeacon(beacon: CLBeacon) -> String {
  return "\(beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString) \(beacon.major) \(beacon.minor)"
}

func purgeExpiredBeacons() {
  let now = NSDate()
  var changed = false
  var newTrackedBeacons = Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>()
  var newTrackedBeaconTimes = Dictionary<String, NSDate>()
  for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
    let beacon = trackedBeacons[key]
    let lastSeenTime = trackedBeaconTimes[key]!
    if now.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastSeenTime) > expirationTimeSecs {
      NSLog("******* Expired seeing beacon: \(key) time interval is \(now.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastSeenTime))")
      changed = true
    }
    else {
      newTrackedBeacons[key] = beacon!
      newTrackedBeaconTimes[key] = lastSeenTime
    }
  }
  if changed {
    trackedBeacons = newTrackedBeacons
    trackedBeaconTimes = newTrackedBeaconTimes
  }
}
```

Comment: The expiration time of 5 secs just discards beacons that are no longer visible after that time.  Turning off Bluetooth should not affect the algorithm.  Are you sure the device is still detecting after the toggle?

Comment: Yes, it is. Debugging it further it seems that after toggling bluetooth off / on, statement "if (beacon != closestBeaconCandidate)" evaluates to false so variable "changed" never becomes true and thus won't calculate the closestBeacon. All of this works if I don't toggle bluetooth off/on though.